# Spliting a string - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to split a string so it looks like this:

```
["Date", "Start Time", "End Time", "Course Code", "Course Name", "Type", "Room", "Building", "Groups"]
```

The string that I'm trying to split looks something like this:

```
2024-03-21, 13:15 - 15:00 MVE545,  Mathematical analysis, part 2,  Lecture,  Omega,  0,  Jupiter,  TIDAL-1, TIELL-1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
```

My first thought is to split the string by ", " but that will mess up the course name since it contains ", ".

Another problem is that a course could have multiple course codes. Then the string would look like this:

```
2024-03-21, 13:15 - 15:00 MVE545, MVE545,  Mathematical analysis, part 2,  Lecture,  Omega,  0,  Jupiter,  TIDAL-1, TIELL-1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
```

Comment: You might want to check out [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rHKJ5q/1).

Comment: If each string has the same format, maybe it is possible to use that information. Split the whole string by spaces or comma, and put some parts together. And yes, if you really have a lot of time, the correct way to do that would be with regex ...

Comment: If you're in control of the generation of that dataset, I'd consider proper CSV encoding

Comment: Only you know the possible variations in content and format. If you can first write down the logical approach to splitting the text string then that can then be coded using regex.

Comment: **If** no other field can contain commas, you can assume in `result = line.split(',')` that `result[0:2]` contains the date, start and stop times, and course code, and that `result[-12:]` contains everything *after* the course name, leaving `','.join(result[2:-12])` as the reconstituted course name.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird but I created a solution using `split()` and list slicing

```
def parser(data):
    return [data.split(',')[0]] + [[x.strip() for x in data.split(',')][1].split('-')[0].strip()] + [[y.strip() for y in [x.strip() for x in data.split(',')][1].split('-')][1].split(' ')[0]] + [[[y.strip() for y in [x.strip() for x in data.split(',')][1].split('-')][1].split(' ')[1]] + [x.strip() for x in data.split(',')][2:-14]] + [x.strip() for x in data.split(',')][-14:]
```

Results are:

```
['2024-03-21', '13:15', '15:00', ['MVE545'], 'Mathematical analysis', 'part 2', 'Lecture', 'Omega', '0', 'Jupiter', 'TIDAL-1', 'TIELL-1', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

and

```
['2024-03-21', '13:15', '15:00', ['MVE545', 'MVE545'], 'Mathematical analysis', 'part 2', 'Lecture', 'Omega', '0', 'Jupiter', 'TIDAL-1', 'TIELL-1', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```